# Does Istio not support wss?

Tags: websocket, istio, istio-gateway

Although I have read many articles, it seems that few people are discussing this problem, and I have not seen any solutions. I would like to know whether wss is not supported after using Istio as the entry point? According to my test, it seems that wss really can't run on istio, but ws is normal, gateway & virtualservice I have done the following test.

Hope someone can discuss this with me, even if it turns out that Istio doesn't support wss, thanks!

1.use tls.mode: PASSTHROUGH

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: test-ws-gw
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
    hosts:
    - "test.ws.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: test-ws-vs
  namespace: ws-test
spec:
  hosts:
  - test.ws.com
  gateways:
  - istio-system/test-ws-gw
  tls:
    - match:
        - port: 443
          sniHosts:
            - "test.ws.com"
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 9400
            host: ws-svc.ws-test.svc.cluster.local
```

2. use tls.mode: SIMPLE

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: test-ws-gw
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: ingress-cert-ws
    hosts:
    - "*"

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: test-ws-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "test.ws.com"
  gateways:
  - test-ws-gw
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9400
        host: ws-svc.ws-test.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using version 1.20.3, and it can use wss successfully.

my configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
# MQTT Broker
  - port:
      number: 1883
      name: mqtt
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - test-mqtt-broker.com
  - port:
      number: 9090
      name: websocket
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
    hosts:
    - test-mqtt-broker.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-tcp
  namespace: mosquitto-prod
spec:
  hosts:
  - test-mqtt-broker.com
  gateways:
  - istio-system/istio-gateway
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 1883
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mosquitto-v2015
        port:
          number: 1883
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-ws
  namespace: mosquitto-prod
spec:
  hosts:
  - test-mqtt-broker.com
  gateways:
  - istio-system/istio-gateway
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 9090
      sniHosts:
      - test-mqtt-broker.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mosquitto-v2015
        port:
          number: 9090
      weight: 100
```